# Creating a dictionary from a dictionary using a tuple Python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

given a dictionary with N keys and a tuple of K keys, K<=N is there a pythonic way to get a dictionary with only the K keys?

ex.

```
orig_dict = {'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2', ..., 'keyN':'valueN'}

tuple = ('key2', 'keyM')

newdict = myFunc(orig_dict, tuple)

print newdict
```

Output:

```
'key2':'value2', 'keyM':'valueM'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
{k:v for k,v in orig_dict.iteritems() if k in tuple_keys}
```

Observe:

```
>>> orig_dict = {'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2', 'keyN':'valueN'}
>>> tuple_keys = ('key2', 'keyN')
>>> {k:v for k,v in orig_dict.iteritems() if k in tuple_keys}
{'keyN': 'valueN', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a comprehension:

```
tple = ('key2', 'keyM')
{k: orig_dict[k] for k in tple}
```

Or if you prefer functional:

```
from operator import itemgetter

dict(zip(tple, itemgetter(*tple)(orig_dict)))
```

What is more *pythonic* is debatable, what is definitely not pythonic is using *tuple* as a variable name.

If some keys may not exist you can get the [*intersection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) with [*viewkeys*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys):

```
dict(zip(tuple, itemgetter(*orig_dict.viewkeys() & tple)(orig_dict)))

{k : orig_dict[k] for k in orig_dict.viewkeys() & tple}
```

For `python3` just use `.keys()` which  returns a *dict_view* object as opposed to a list in python2.

If you wanted to give a default value of *None* for missing keys, you could also use *map* with *dict.get* so missing keys would have their value set to None.

```
dict(zip(tuple, map(orig_dict.get, tuple)
```

Comment: Beat you to it this time, Mr Cunningham!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, slightly different approaches, I have full faith all the keys are there :) +1 anyway

Comment: :)  for the `itemgetter` approach, +1

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary comprehension

```
orig_dict = {'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2', 'keyN':'valueN'}
keys = ('key2', 'keyM')

>>> {k:orig_dict[k] for k in keys if k in orig_dict}
{'key2': 'value2'}
```

This will be more efficient than iterating over the dictionary's keys and checking whether the key exists in the tuple because it is an O(1) operation to lookup a dict vs O(n) to search in a tuple.

Alternatively you can use a set to get the common keys and combine that with a dict comprehension:

```
>>> {k:orig_dict[k] for k in set(keys).intersection(orig_dict)}
{'key2': 'value2'}
```

Comment: Ah yes. Definitely a better solution. +1